# How to deal with about base conversion in java

Tags: java

I wanna whenever I input a string and a int like this (“1101”, 2) . Method will return 13. But in the question part as below

"For bases beyond 10 use upper- case letters starting with ‘A’ as digits. In base 16 the digits used are therefore ‘0’ through ‘F’. Your method must work with bases in the range 1 through 36."

Whats that really mean, I am so weak at base conversion problem.

Comment: For base 16, A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14, and F = 15. 10 = 16. If you're weak at base conversion -- study it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started. It will convert up to base 9 to base 10. You will have to modify it to work for higher bases, but that shouldn't be too hard. For example, you could use a case statement to convert A-F to their numerical values.

```
 class BaseConvert
    {

        public static int baseTen(String s, int base){

            String[] bits = s.split("");
            int result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++ ){

                int val = (Integer.parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i])) * ((int)Math.pow(base,i));

                result += val;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                 System.out.println(baseTen("1111",2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: String[] bits = s.split("");   What does this mean? I can't understand.

Comment: Split is a function that breaks up a string and puts the pieces into an array. You can choose how you want to split it. In this case, "" means we split each character in the string apart.

Comment: So we take the input string, say, "1101", and separate all the 1's and 0' s. Then we can evaluate the value of each individual bit.

Comment: yea, now I understand that. But int val = (Integer.parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i])) * ((int)Math.pow(base,i));
also this seem complecated May yo explain this please?

Comment: I know bits.length-1-i will execute from very last of the bits ,and Math.pow(base,i) is base power of i times. But I really do not know what does parseInt and (int) means .

Comment: Can I do the thing like              int L = s.length(); for(int p = 0; p<L; p++)          does it do the same thing as String[] bits = s.split("");

Comment: You are right about how the code works. `parseInt` is used because Java doesn't automatically know what type of value you're giving it. You have to tell the program that your individual bits, "1", "0", "1", "1" are integers and not strings. We use `(int)` because `Math.pow()` doesn't necessarily return an integer, it might return a float. For example, `Math.pow(2, 2.5)` would give us `5.66`. Let me know if that makes sense :)

Comment: yea, but I can not understand whats point of int val = (Integer.parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i])) * ((int)Math.pow(base,i)); as a whole. I do not get it what it gonna return as?

Comment: why these two have to * together, what does it means? sorry I am really confuse about it

Comment: oh I see, its because parseInt method is convert every digit from left to decimal. am I right? but I still wanna ask when you run parseInt() method it suppose to be like parseInt(int,int) ,but why you use like parseInt(int*int)

Comment: Each time in the loop it multiplies a bit. So 1*(2^0), 0*(2^1), 1*(2^2), 1*(2^3)

Comment: oh, I got it. and you said that I could use a case statement to convert A-F to their numerical values. but what is case statement?? thank you

Comment: so should I do if(base = 16){A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14, and F = 15. 10 = 16}   if(base = 17){A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14, and F = 15. G = 16 10 = 17} but that so complicated is there any easier way to do that? thank you

Comment: Pretty sure you can figure something out.

Comment: cool I will have a try. I still have problem I ma come there leave comment. thx

Comment: I am still stuck at parseInt method, I google it and it tells me that it was like parseInt(int.int) the first int is the number you wanna convert, and second int is the base. It is different from what you did in parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i]). you just did like parseInt(bits[]), instead of parseInt(int.int). so why you using  parseInt? I just mark it as accepted

Comment: You can also call 'parseInt(String)' which converts the string, e.g, "1", into an integer. Remember that bits[] is an array of strings.

Comment: so why you use Integer   before    .parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i])    Its not work for switch strings in the  bits[] to every single integer?

Comment: I may already figure it out how to convert A-F to their numerical values. but if I type in the common thats gonna look mess up. and I do not wanna ask another question. can you give me your email so that I can send it to you to check if it is right.

Comment: Lol I don't know what you're asking. I've given you all the pieces, all you need is to think about how to put them together

Comment: alright . but  why you use Integer before .parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i]) Its not work for switch strings in the bits[] to every single integer?

Answer (score 0):

> For bases beyond 10 use upper- case letters starting with ‘A’ as digits. In base 16 the digits used are therefore ‘0’ through ‘F’. Your method must work with bases in the range 1 through 36.

Your instructor is defining what characters to use for bases higher than 10.

For example, in base 16, the letters A through F are used as digits.  A in base 16 is equivalent to 10 in base 10.  F in base 16 is equivalent to 15 in base 10.

Here's one hint.  It's much easier to convert a number from an input base to base 10, then convert the number from base 10 to the output base.  It's because we're used to math in base 10.